# Unity element 1

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

I'd like to write the unity element 1 in LaTeX. I have tried these methods:

```
$\mathbbm{1}$ \\
$\mathbb{1}$\\
$\mathbbss{1}$\\
$\mathbbtt{1}$\\
$\mathds{1}$\
```

but I receive the integer 1. I think that I'm missing a suitable package. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this help?: http://www.douglas.stebila.ca/blog/archives/2004/06/27/latex-blackboard-bold-1/

Comment: If you load the package `bbold`, you can type `\mathbb{1}` (in math-mode, of course) to get what you want. The "standard" blackboard bold glyphs are available only for uppercase letters -- hence the need to load an extra package.

Comment: @Mico I believe you have answered the question. I recommend you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @azetina: done!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "standard" blackboard bold math font contains only uppercase latin-alphabet letters. To get a blackboard bold "1" symbol, you need to load an additional LaTeX package.

For instance, the commands `\mathbb{1}` (load the `bbold` package) and `\mathds{1}` (load the `dsfont` package) will generate:

[image]

respectively.

Comment: It's been 12 years, but I just stumbled upon this post. I believe the second package is called \usepackage{dsfont}

Comment: @infinitezero - You're absolutely right! Many thanks for pointing it out. I'll fix this issue right away.